# How to convert Python Pandas function to Python PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm currently having a problem with converting Python Pandas function into Python PySpark as both are different libraries. What I would like to do is to have a query function and then apply that back to the same column.

This is what I have done for Python Pandas (Age is the column in my dataset that I am trying to retrieve from):

```
Age = [1, 3, -100, -99999,  39, 60, 87, 20,  21,  77777]

def clean_age(Age):
    if Age>=0 and Age<=95:
        return Age
    else:
        return np.nan

df['Age'] = df['Age'].apply(clean_age)
```

It works fine for Python Pandas but now this is what I have done for Python PySpark and it doesn't work:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def clean_age(Age):
    if Age>=0 and Age<=95:
        return Age
    else:
        return NaN

spark.udf.register("clean_age", clean_age)
udf_myFunction = udf(clean_age, IntegerType())
new_df2 = new_df.withColumn('Age_Clean',udf_myFunction('Age'))
new_df2.show()
```

Please advise on how can I implement what I have from Pandas to PySpark. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look at using a `pandas_udf`. This is for `Spark >= 2.3.0` (albeit for function your complexity this might be an overkill):

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType


# your function, a and b are assumed to be type pd.Series
def my_func(a, b):
    return a * b


pandas_func = f.pandas_udf(my_func, returnType=LongType())

# create test dataframe
x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["x"]))

# apply pandas_func
df.select(pandas_func(f.col("x"), f.col("x"))).show()
+-----------------+
|pandas_func(x, x)|
+-----------------+
|                1|
|                4|
|                9|
+-----------------+
```

If you wish to avoid `pandas_udf`, any version of `Spark >= 2.0.0` can leverage `pyspark.sql.functions.when` and `otherwise`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

x = pd.Series([10, 777, -3, 22])
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["Age"]))

df.withColumn(
  "Age",
  f.when(
    (f.col("Age") >= 0) & 
    (f.col("Age") <= 95), f.col("Age")).otherwise(f.lit(None))
)
```

Feel free to wrap the `df.withColumn` in a function and then call the function with argument `df` and returning `df.withColumn`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Does pandas_udf works in Jupyter Notebook? I tried to import the function but it said cannot import name 'pandas_udf'

Comment: @devaaron what is your Spark version? You can find it out using `sc.version` or `spark._sc.version` or just by returning from your `SparkSession` or `SparkContext`.

Comment: I SSH through AWS and I can't find what version of Spark I am using for Jupyter Notebook. Does it matter what version it is on? I would presume it is on the latest version.

Comment: It does depend a lot - `pandas_udf` was released relatively recently so some old clusters may not have it. In jupyter notebook do the following: `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`, then `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`, then get output of `spark`.

Comment: Would  this ```spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() ``` wrap in something? Can you please show me the full example please? I am still unable to make pandas_udf work. I guess the Jupyter Notebook might be quite old or something. Is there any other way to achieve without using Pandas?

Comment: Nope - you would just import `SparkSession` as indicated above and call that. Then `spark` returns a link to `Spark UI` and version. I've updated the answer with a standalone logic using `pyspark.sql.functions.when`.

Comment: @devaaron is there a reason for the downvote? The solution above is tested and does what is requested by the question, while you were not able to provide additional information, such as what version of spark you're running. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @napolean_borntoparty I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: I have tried your solution without using pandas_udf. This is what I have:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
new_df.withColumn(
  "Age",
  f.when(
    (f.col("Age") >= 0) & 
    (f.col("Age") <= 95), f.col("Age")).otherwise(f.lit(None))
)

new_df.select('Age').distinct().show(1000, False)
```

It is still not returning back the correct Age condition, not sure why.

Comment: Aaaah, I see - the `new_df.withColumn(...)` does not alter the underlying dataframe as it would in pandas. Instead, you need to assign into a variable, such as `new_df = new_df.withColumn("Age", f.when(...))`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Create udf:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
age_check_udf = udf(lambda age: age if (age >= 0 and age <= 95) else np.nan, IntegerType())
```

Call from Dataframe:

```
new_df2 = new_df.withColumn('Age_Clean', age_check_udf(new_df.Age))
new_df2.show()
```

Comment: new_df2 would be the new Dataframe right? I tried to call it with new_df2.show() for example, it doesn't work. Why is that? It works for .count() but not when I tried to show the results.